# Amazon Redshift schema design

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, data-warehouse

We are looking at Amazon Redshift to implement our Data Warehouse and I would like some suggestions on how to properly design Schemas in Redshift, please.

I am completely new to Redshift. In the past when I worked with "traditional" data warehouses, I was used to creating schemas such as "Source", "Stage", "Final", etc. to group all the database objects according to what stage the data was in.

By default, a database in Redshift has a single schema, which is named PUBLIC. So, my question to those who have worked with Redshift, does the approach that I have outlined above apply here? If not, I would love some suggestions.

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With my experience in working with Redshift, I can assert the following points with confidence:

1. **Multiple schema**: You should create multiple schema and create tables accordingly. When you'll scale, it'll be easier for you to pin-point where exactly the table is supposed to be. Let us say, you have 3 schema, named `production`, `aggregates` and `rough`. Now, you know that the table **`production`** will contain the tables that are not supposed to be changed (mostly OLTP data) - such as `user, order, transactions` tables. Table **`aggregates`** will have aggregated data built over raw tables - such as `number of orders placed per user per day per category`. Finally, **`rough`** will contain any table that doesn't hold a business logic but is required for some temporary work - let us say to check the genre of movies for a list of 1 lakh users, which is shared with you in an excel file. Simply create a table in `rough` schema, perform your operations and drop the table. Now you very clearly know where you'll find the tables based on whether they are raw, aggregated or simply temporary tables.
2. **Public schema**: Forget it exists. Any table that is not preceded with a schema name, gets created there. A lot of clutter - no point in storing any important data there.
3. **Cross schema joins:** There's no stopping here. You may join as many tables from as many schema as required. In fact, it is desirable you create dimension tables and join on a PK later, rather than to keep all the information in a single table.

Spend some quality time in designing the schema and underlying table structure. When you expand, it'll be easier for you to classify things better in terms of access control. Do let me know if I've missed some obvious points.

Comment: You have a typo: 

"Now, you know that the table production..." 

should be instead 

" Now, you know that the schema production..."

(I tried to edit this but I got "There are to many pending edits on Stack Overflow, please. try again later")

Answer (score 3):

You can have multiple databases in a Redshift cluster but I would stick with one. You are correct that schemas (essentially namespaces) are a good way to divide things up. You can query across schemas but not databases.

I would avoid using the public schema as managing certain permissions there can be difficult (easier to deny someone access to public than prevent them from being able to create a table for example).

For best results if you have the time, learn about the permissions system up front. You want to [create groups that have access to schemas or tables](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/t_user_group_examples.html) and add/remove users from groups to control what they can do. Once you have that going it becomes pretty easy to manage.

Comment: "You can have multiple databases in a Redshift cluster but I would stick with one" - It would be helpful if you say why.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the other responses, here are some suggestions for improving schema performance.

First:  Automatic compression encodings using COPY command

Improve the performance of Amazon Redshift using the COPY command. It will get data into Redshift database. The COPY command is clever enough. It automatically chooses the most appropriate encoding settings for the data it uploads. You don’t have to think about it. However, it does so only for the first data upload into an empty table.

So, make sure to use a significant data set while uploading data for the first time, which Redshift can assess to set the column encodings in the best way. Uploading a few lines of test data will confuse Redshift to know how best to optimize the compression to handle the real workload.

Second: Use Best Distribution Style and Key

Distribution-style decides how data is distributed across the nodes. Applying a distribution style at table level tells Redshift how you want to distribute the table and the key. So, how you specify distribution style is important for good query performance with Redshift. The style you choose may affect requirements for data storage and cluster. It also affects the time taken by the COPY command to execute.

I recommend setting the distribution style to all tables with a smaller dimension. For large dimension, distribute both the dimension and associated fact on their join column. To optimize the second large dimension, take the storage-hit and distribute ALL. You can even design the dimension columns into the fact.

Third: Use the Best Sort Key

A Redshift database maintains data in a table with an arrangement of a sort-key-column if specified. Since it’s sorted in each partition; each cluster node upholds its partition in predefined order. (While designing your Redshift schema, also consider the impact on your budget. Redshift is [priced](https://blog.panoply.io/data-engineers-guide-to-redshift-pricing) by amount of stored data and by the number of nodes.)

Sort key optimizes Amazon Redshift performance significantly. You can do it in many ways. First, use data filtering. If where-clause filters on a sort-key-column, it skips the entire data blocks. It’s because Redshift saves data in blocks. Each block header records the minimum and maximum sort key value. Filter outside of that range, the entire block may get skipped.

Alternatively, when joining two tables, sorted on their joint keys, the data is read in matching order. Also, you can merge-join without separate sort-steps. Joining large dimension to a large fact table will be easy with this method because neither will fit into a hash table.